# Как вывести/синхронизировать конфиг apache2 из docker-compose?

Tags: php, laravel, docker, symfony3, docker-compose

У меня есть docker-compose сборка локального веб-сервера:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:7.1-apache

RUN apt-get update &&\
apt-get install --no-install-recommends --assume-yes --quiet ca-certificates 
curl git &&\
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN pecl install xdebug-2.5.5 && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
RUN echo 'zend_extension="/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-
20151012/xdebug.so"' >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
RUN echo 'xdebug.remote_port=9000' >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
RUN echo 'xdebug.remote_enable=1' >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
RUN echo 'xdebug.remote_connect_back=1' >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
```

**php.ini**

```
zend_extension="/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-
20151012/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
  services:
   apache_with_php:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

Сейчас **Document root** это локальная папка в **src** в корне.

***Проблема:*** На данный момент эта сборка должна служить под развертывание php фреймворков (Laravel,Symfony). Но для их работы/установки нужно править apache2. По ssh заходить и править конфиг - я считаю не правильным и не практичным, нужно чтобы конфиг лежал в локальной папке и при редактировании синхронизировался с тем что в контейнере.

Как  это сделать? (в данный момент нужно Symfony 3.3 развернуть)

Comment: В Dockerfile через COPY

Comment: @Invision Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Можно пробросить конфиги в контейнер

```
volumes:
  - ./httpd/httpd.conf:/etc/httpd/httpd.conf
```